# Transferring docs to records library

Tags: sharepoint-server

I apoligize in advance if my title to this is way off base but there could be several different possible names and I can't figure out which one works best.

My issue...

I have three document libraries on Site 1 that I am trying to transfer to three different document libraries for retention in my records center.  I have three sendto connections to the Records center that all test out and I created a retention policies in each of the libraries within the Information management policy settings in the Document content type.  I have each of the document libraries transferring to its respective document library in the records center but they all keep going into the same document library and I cannot figure out how to separate them.

I hope this does not completely confuse anyone trying to help me out.  It seems pretty straight forward to me.. but I guess not.

Site 1:  Drop off Library for Bank statements  transfers to Bank statements on the Records library

Site 1:  Drop off Library for historical transfers to historical in the Records Library.

Site 1: Drop off Library for Investment files transfers to Investment files in the records library.

For some reason all my files keep going to the Historical library in the records library.  I'm kind of lost...

Hope someone can help!

thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1):

After reading some of the related links on this site I realized I forgot to go into the content organizer rules to set up the path to the library I want the doc to go to.  IMO to many steps for something you think should be "simple".